# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' in 'F:\Angular\HttpServices\http-services\src\app'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Here is my code.

```
import { injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostsService {
    private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    constructor(private http : Http ) { }
    getPosts {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    } 

    deletePost(id) {
        return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + id);
    }
}
```

I am doing this code on my PC it's working but not working on a laptop. It seems funny but this is true.
This is the structure of my project

Comment: Did you do `npm install` to get all dependencies

Comment: May be an newer version of rxjs which no longer supports single imports. Try `import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators;'

Comment: Yes @ShashankVivek I tried using npm install as well as npm update

Comment: Module '"f:/Angular/angular-form/angular-form-app/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'. i am getting this error now

Comment: Angular CLI : 1.7.4 and
Angular CLI : 6.0.1
What is the difference between this two ?

Comment: Try : `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 19):

New version of rxjs no longer supports single imports, instead try:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 18):

In Angular 6 RXJS imports have been changed, operators must be "wrapped" in pipe() and written without a dot at the beginning (was: .map, .retry, .catch; now: map, retry and catchError instead of a catch):

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and use pipe()

```
getPosts() {
    // pack in "pipe()"
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      // eg. "map" without a dot before
      map(data => {
        return data;
      }),
      // "catchError" instead "catch"
      catchError(error => {
        return Observable.throw('Something went wrong ;)');
      })
    );
  }
```

"I am doing this code on my PC it's working but not working on a laptop" - on the laptop you've a newer version of angular cli. It generates angular 6 with new, other imports. Regards

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

If you came here because of a Udemy Course which the initial code suggests.

imports

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And this is how it should look now.

```
  deletePost(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id ).pipe(
       catchError(error => {
         return throwError(() => new Error("..."));
      }));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

in angular 7, here is how to handle in a clean way the http get request

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {

    return this._http.get(<URL>).pipe(
      retry(1), catchError(error => {
        return throwError(error.message);
      }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this and will work!...

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';    
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';    
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';    


        .get(<URL>).pipe
         (
         catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>{       
            return throwError(error.message || 'server error');    
                                                })
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

**For recent versions of Angular (v13)**, the code is a bit different. Let's start with the service implementation:

```
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from '../common/app-error';
...
      deletePost(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id).pipe(
          catchError((error: Response) => {
            if (error.status === 404)
              return throwError(() => new NotFoundError(error));
            return throwError(() => new AppError(error));
          })
        );
      }
```

For a Separation of concerns purpose, the service is responsible for sending the delete request and catching any potential known (not found 404) or unknown error. In case of an error, the service throws an error by calling one of the application error classes (AppError which is a generic class and NotFoundError which is a specific error class and it extends AppError).

Note that the service delegates the error management to thoses 2 error application classes (the service role is not to go into error management details)

AppError (app-error.ts):

```
export class AppError {
  constructor(public originalError?: any) {}
}
```

NotFoundError (not-found-error.ts):

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';
export class NotFoundError extends AppError {}
```

Now for the posts.component.ts implementation, we should have something like:

```
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
...
  deletePost(post: any) {
    this.service.deletePost(post.id).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
        this.posts.splice(index, 1);
      },
      error: (error: AppError) => {
        if (error instanceof NotFoundError)
          alert('this post has already been deleted');
        else {
          alert('An unexpected error occured.');
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
    });
  }
```

This deletePost method subscribes to the dedicated service, and in case the service catches and throws an error, deletePost will check the kind of the error and will show the error accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try adding "import 'rxjs/add/operators/catch';" (put the 's' and make it operators) instead of "import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';"